# Flutter Integration Test - import local dart file

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, flutter-integration-test

I'm writing some flutter integration tests that I want to run utilising flutter drive to see them in action. The tests work as expected when running good old `flutter test`.

I'm trying to run the very same tests using `flutter drive`, where they worked when I had all the code in the single file, but now I've refactored into multiple files, it doesn't work.

I've separated out some of my tester actions in to a separate dart file, so I can complete tests with a robot style approach. But now that I import my robot in to the test, I get the following error when running flutter drive:

> org-dartlang-app:/my_end_to_end_test.dart:7:8: Error: Error when
> reading 'org-dartlang-app:/robots/add_items_to_list_robot.dart': File
> not found import '../robots/add_items_to_list_robot.dart';

Here is an example of the test and robot too:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';

import '../robots/add_items_to_list_robot.dart';

void main(){
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setupLocator();

  group('List should', () { 
     testWidgets('Add an item when the add button is selected', () async {
        // Given
        await tester.pumpWidget(const myApp());

        // When
        await tester.typeTextInTextArea('My list item');
        await tester.clickAddToListButton();

        // Then
        expect(this, that); // You know what I'm getting at
     });
  });
}
```

```
extension ListItemRobot on WidgetTest {
   Future<void> typeTextInTextArea(String text) {
       // This gets the text area, enters the text
       await pumpAndSettle();
   }

   Future<void> clickAddToListButton() {
       final button = find.byKey(Key('AddButton'));

       await tap(button);
       await pumpAndSettle();
   }
}
```